# return not work when I use setTimeout in try-catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have this try-catch block:

```
async function matchMaking(userId) {
  try {

    const user = await User.findOne({
      _id: userId
    });

    var timeOut1 = setTimeout(function() {
      return {
        success: false,
        msg: "matchMaking aleready done"
      };
    }, 20000);

    //some code
    if (match === true) {
      clearTimeout(timeOut1);
      return {
        success: true
      };
    }

  } catch (e) {
    return {
      success: false,
      error: e
    };
  }
}
```

And I used it as follows:

```
matchMaking(userId).then(res => {
  if (res.success) {
    console.log("success")
  } else {
    console.log("failed")
  }
});
```

When ( match === true ) its OK and i get "success" in console, But when ( match === false), I expect to see the "failed" in the console after 20 seconds.
But return does not work in setTimeout  and I do not get anything.

Comment: Think about what function that `return` is actually in.

Comment: need a promise that resolves/rejects in the setTimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a `Promise` from the matchMaking function.

```
async function matchMaking (userId) {

    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        const user = await User.findOne({
            _id: userId
        });
        var timeOut1 = setTimeout(function() {
            return res({
                success: false,
                msg: "matchMaking aleready done"
            });
        }, 20000);

        if (match === true) {
            clearTimeout(timeOut1);
            return res({
                success: true
            });
        }
    });
}
```

That way, when you call it like this - it will behave as expected:

```
matchMaking(userId).then(res => {
  if (res.success) {
    console.log("success")
  } else {
    console.log("failed")
  }
});
```

A better way to handle it would be to use a the `reject` callback of the promise:

```
async function matchMaking (userId) {

    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        const user = await User.findOne({
            _id: userId
        });
        var timeOut1 = setTimeout(function() {
            return rej({
                success: false,
                msg: "matchMaking aleready done"
            });
        }, 20000);

        if (match === true) {
            clearTimeout(timeOut1);
            return res({
                success: true
            });
        }
    });
}
```

That way, when you call it like this - you can use `.catch()` to handle the failed state:

```
matchMaking(userId)
    .then(res => console.log("success"))
    .catch(err => console.log("failed"));
```